# Compile x264 with Thread Support for Android Platform

Tags: android, android-ndk, pthreads, x264, libx264

I've been tryin' to compile **x264** for **Android** with Thread Support...But with no success...

I've managed to compile the same without thread support...The configure command is as follows :

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-pic \
--host=arm-linux \
--disable-cli \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM
```

where `PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86` and
`PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm`

I've also tried with and without the option `--enable-static` and `extra-ldflags="-lpthread"`, but when attempted `make` it ends with errors.

Is there any way to accomplish the above said...?

Comment: What errors are given?

Comment: Look into config.log file created during configure. There should be few (around 4) pthread_create tests which failed. Your task is to read why they failed and change configure accordingly that at least one of them wouldn't fail. Also you can add --extra-cflags="-v" to configure so the gcc output will be more verbose to find out which pathes are used for headers and libraries search.

Comment: @nobody555 : Would try that and report the same as soon as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that seemed to appear in `config.log` in context to thread support was `cannot find lpthread`...
That got resolved by manually removing the `-lpthread` from the `configure` file.
But then the configuration started failing at the test that included the `struct cpu_set_t` and `CPU_COUNT()`...

Seems that certain `libc` functions and definitions are not included in the code provided with **Android NDK (R8D)**...In the above case `CPU_COUNT()` and the definition for `struct cpu_set_t`...

The workaround for the above was to patch `sched.h` with the [latest version](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/sched.h)...
There are a few bug reports in the Android Issue List describing the same problem which would hopefully be addressed in the next NDK release...

Also `x264` could be compiled to include the  " ARM Support Feature " by including the option `--extra-cflags="-mfloat-abi=softfp"`...